# AWS RDS MariaDB capacity planning

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

Customer has provisioned following for AWS RDS MariaDB instance:

Instance type: db.m5.large, vCPUs: 2, RAM: 8 GB, Multi AZ: No, Replication: No, Storage: 100 GB, Type: General purpose SSD

We are not sure what is the basis for provisioning the instance. Questions are:

1. What all factors should be considered to do capacity planning?
2. Is this a typical production grade database configuration?

Comment: multiaz should be enabled for production DBs. The sizing is highly dependent on usage. Note that with gp2 storage, your IOPs are based on the total size.

Comment: @jordanm I understand this. Question is: How do I quantify usage? Number of queries? IOPS? Throughput?

Answer (score 0):

Since

> Customer has provisioned

we should account for customer's opinion and consider the factors which let them arrive to this plan, however there are factors which can help you in capacity planning i.e

- If the transaction size static or dynamic.
- If it is dynamic what could be the maximum transaction size.
- What is the amount of network bandwidth each transaction is going to consume.
- Will the number of transaction grow over the time ( it is suppose to grow anyways)
- About production grade database configuration is anyways subjective question and can be debated however a basic architecture which is production grade looks like below -

[image: DevOps Architecure]

[Aws Pricing calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/estimate) is a good place to start with for most of the factors which should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Build the system on your laptop.  If it scales well enough there, get an RDS of similar specs.

If it clearly does not scale well enough, get an RDS of the size up.  Then work on optimizing things.

In some situations, you may have a slow query that just needs a better index.  Keep in mind that "throwing hardware at a problem" is rarely optimal.

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible to answer this question without knowing the exact specifics of the workload. However, it is unusual to have only 8GB of RAM for a 100GB database size. This puts you, optimistically, at about 5% ratio between buffer pool (cache) and data size, so unless the amount of hot data is surprisingly small in the specific workload that is intended, you will probably want at least double that amount of memory.